# Parse Cloud Code Chain Promises

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to clean my Parse Cloud Code functions to make them easier to maintain.
To do so I tried to use Promises but I can't get rid of errors.

Here is the aim of my code :

- Decrement score of **User1**
- Push a notification to **User2** saying --> **User1.name** is asking you to : **Action**

### Actual Cloud Code (working) :

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var action = request.object.get("action");
var from = request.object.get("from");
var to = request.object.get("to");
var reward = request.object.get("reward");

// Query 'from User' to decrement his score
var queryScore = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
queryScore.get(from.id, {
  success: function(score)
  {
    // Decrement score of 'fromUser'.
    var newScore = score.get("score");
    newScore -= reward;
    score.set("score", newScore);

    score.save(null, {
      success: function(success)
      {
        // Score was saved.
        // Find devices associated with 'to User'
        var queryTo = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        queryTo.equalTo("objectId", to.id);
        var pushQueryTo = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        pushQueryTo.matchesQuery("user", queryTo);

        pushQueryTo.first({
          success: function(installation)
          {
            // Device found
            // Fetch 'from User' infos
            from.fetch({
              success: function(User) {

                // 'from User' fetched
                // Send Push to 'to User'
                var first_name = User.get("first_name");

                var preferredLanguages = installation.get("preferredLanguages");
                var alert = ""

                switch (preferredLanguages) {
                  case "fr":
                    alert = first_name + " vous demande de : " + action
                    break;
                  default:
                    alert = first_name + " is asking you to : " + action
                }

                Parse.Push.send({
                    where: pushQueryTo,
                    data: {
                      "alert": alert,
                      "badge": "Increment",
                      "content-available": "1",
                      "type": "actionAsked",
                      "sound": "default"
                    }
                  });

                  // Everything is done!
                  response.success();

              },
              error: function(error) {
                // An error occurred.
                response.error(error);
              }
            });
          },
          error: function(error)
          {
            // An error occurred.
            response.error(error);
          }
        });
      },
      error: function(error)
      {
        // An error occurred.
        response.error(error);
      }
    });

  },
  error: function(error)
  {
    // An error occurred.
    response.error(error);
  }
});
```

### Chain Promises Cloud Code (not working) :

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var action = request.object.get("action");
var from = request.object.get("from");
var to = request.object.get("to");
var reward = request.object.get("reward");

// Query 'from User' to decrement his score
var queryScore = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
queryScore.get(from.id).then(function(score) {

    // Decrement score of 'fromUser'.
    var newScore = score.get("score");
    newScore -= reward;
    score.set("score", newScore);

    return score.save();

}).then(function(result) {

    // Score was saved.
    // Find devices associated with 'to User'
    var queryTo = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    queryTo.equalTo("objectId", to.id);
    var pushQueryTo = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQueryTo.matchesQuery("user", queryTo);

    return pushQueryTo.first();

}).then(function(device) {

    // Device found
    // Fetch 'from User' infos

    return from.fetch();

}).then(function(from){

    // 'from User' fetched
    // Send Push to 'to User'
    var first_name = from.get("first_name");
    var preferredLanguages = device.get("preferredLanguages");
    var alert = ""

    switch (preferredLanguages) {
        case "fr":
            alert = first_name + " vous demande de : " + action
            break;
        default:
            alert = first_name + " is asking you to : " + action
    }

    Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQueryTo,
        data: {
            "alert": alert,
            "badge": "Increment",
            "content-available": "1",
            "type": "actionAsked",
            "sound": "default"
        }
    });

    // Everything is done!
    response.success();

},function(error) {

    // An error occurred.
    response.error(error);

});
```

### The error I get :

Apparently my error is concerning the "device" variable.

Comment: Can you give the actual error?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the "device" variable. When I try to get  "preferredLanguages" from the variable it says that "device" was not defined.

Comment: This indicates that `return pushQueryTo.first();` is not returning a value. What does `first()` do and what does it return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In converting to promises you have also un-nested, causing `device` and `pushQueryTo` no longer to be in scope in later handlers. With nicely indented code (as in the question), scope issues like this are readily observable in the source.

Fortunately, wherever a `then()` handler returns a promise, you are afforded some freedom to chain directly to the expression that returns that promise, instead of adding to the outermost promise chain.

A fix here is simply to re-introduce some of the nesting by chaining directly to `pushQueryTo.first()` and `from.fetch()`.

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var action = request.object.get("action");
var from = request.object.get("from");
var to = request.object.get("to");
var reward = request.object.get("reward");

var queryScore = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
queryScore.get(from.id)
.then(function(score) {
    score.set('score', score.get('score') - reward);
    return score.save();
})
.then(function(result) {
    var queryTo = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    queryTo.equalTo('objectId', to.id);
    var pushQueryTo = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQueryTo.matchesQuery('user', queryTo);
    return pushQueryTo.first()
    .then(function(device) {
        return from.fetch()
        .then(function(from) {
            var alert;
            switch (device.get('preferredLanguages')) {
                case 'fr': alert = from.get('first_name') + ' vous demande de : ' + action; break;
                default: alert = from.get('first_name') + ' is asking you to : ' + action;
            }
            Parse.Push.send({
                where: pushQueryTo,
                data: { 'alert': alert, 'badge': 'Increment', 'content-available': '1', 'type': 'actionAsked', 'sound': 'default' }
            });
            response.success();
        });
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
    response.error(error);
});
```

Please note that I said this is "a" solution, not "the" solution. In other words, other approaches exist. The whole topic of accessing previous promise results in a .then() chain is discussed very comprehensively **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/)** .

Comment: Thanks for you complete answer. I just had to change the error function to make it work
`},function(error) {
     response.error(error);
 }); `

Comment: @MatthieuTnsc , are you sure that's necessary? A single `catch()` as I wrote it, should catch any error, even from the inner promise chain. An inner catch would typically be necessary only if it treated the error differently from the outer - eg an intermediate error recovery.

Comment: I get the following error with the catch error syntax --> `Error: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'catch' at main.js:50:15`

Comment: Ah, OK I misunderstood your comment. It appears that Parse promises do not have a `catch()` method.

Comment: thanks for this lovely answer. @Roamer-1888, you may possibly have advice on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768731) puzzle I'm facing  :O